# Error (mysqli_fetch_array) en consulta después de hacer una inserción múltiple

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos necesito saber por favor cual es mi error no lo encuentro por más que me fijo no se cual sea ya utilice el var_dum y al parecer no me ejecuta la consulta acaso será porque ya ejecute los insert y eso interviene para la segunda consulta, Ayuda por favor. Gracias.  Aclaro que los insert si funcionan. Ya que cuando borro el código de la $consulta2 todo funciona bien, es por eso que me imprime éxito del ajax.

Mi código .php

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

    $array_resultados = array();
    $array_id_perfiles = array();
    $array_resultados_finales = array();
    $datos = array();

    $sql = "";  

    $id_estudiante = $_GET['id_alumno'];
    $array_resultados = $_GET['resultados'];

    $longitud_array = sizeof($array_resultados);


    include_once('../../Verificacion/Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php');


    $consulta = "SELECT id_perfil from perfil"; 

    $resultados_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados_consulta)){
        array_push ($array_id_perfiles, $registro[0]);
    }

    //Preparar los insert de cada resultado
    for($i=0; $i < $longitud_array; $i++){

        $resultado = $array_resultados[$i];
        $id_perfil = $array_id_perfiles[$i];

        $sql .= "INSERT INTO puntajes (resultado, id_alumno, id_perfil) VALUES ('$resultado', '$id_estudiante', '$id_perfil');";
    }

    if($conexion->multi_query($sql) === true){

        $consulta2 = "SELECT nombre_perfil from puntajes, perfil where perfil.id_perfil = puntajes.id_perfil and id_alumno = '$id_estudiante' order by resultado DESC limit 0,3;";
        $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);


        while($resultados_finales = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
            array_push($array_resultados_finales, $resultados_finales[0]);
        }

        $datos["resultados_finales"] = $array_resultados_finales;
        $datos["estado"] = "exito";


    }else{
         printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
         $datos["estado"] = "error";
    }

    $conexion->close();

    $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';
```

Mi error:

> **Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given
>   jQuery33107542014014811786_1533317624253({"resultados_finales":[],"estado":"exito"});

Comment: Eso es por que tu consulta tronó en la base de datos, seguro que así se llama el campo y la tabla?
Retorna un array de strings que corresponde a la fila obtenida o NULL si no hay más filas en el resultset.

Comment: Por supuesto amigo ya probé mi consulta en phpmyadmin y funciona. Comentario corregido jeje. Y si me sigue marcando error.

Comment: El asunto es que la consulta no esta arrojando resultados basados en los parametros que llegan por get, a lo que deberías de crear una validación, pues el codigo se continua ejecutando aun cuando depende de que la primera consulta arroje resultados, y si no hay obtienes dicho error. Como puedes apreciar te retorna el error de php no controlado por ti. simplemente con validar un `mysqli_num_rows($resultados_consulta)` y validar si es mayor a cero controlarías el flujo de la respuesta.